# Right-to-left label for cesiumjs

Tags: cesium

I am trying to use right to left language in CesiumJS label, but the result is reverse ordered. What can I do?

```
 viewer.entities.add({
        position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.59777, 40.03883),
        point : {
            pixelSize : 10,
            color : Cesium.Color.YELLOW
        },
        label : {text : "מה המצב" }
    });
```

Yields image:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reversing the string order did the trick:

```
viewer.entities.add({
  position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.59777, 40.03883),
  point : {
      pixelSize : 10,
      color : Cesium.Color.YELLOW
  },
  label : {text : reverse("מה המצב") }
});
```

Where reverse is something like

```
function reverse(s) {
  var o = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = s.length; i <= len; i++)
    o.push(s.charAt(len - i));
  return o.join('');
}
```

[image]